# Help to Setup a Monero mining farm $4000 Budget

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining-hardware, mining-pool-setup, solo-mining

After to try some pools and alt cryptocoins by some weeks, I'm now really serious about to make a Monero farm because I believe in this potential, Monero is Awesome!

Today I mine in DwarfPool, just more couple of days to get my 0.1 XMR to try others pools or mine solo.

My miners today:

- A raspberry pi 3 running cpuminer-multi – Was very fun configure this
  mini miner with 10h/s, but soon he will be only my media center,
  arcade and cold storage
- My computer brings 66h/s (4 threads) with a i5 2400 running cpuminer-sandybridge-ivybridge and 528h/s with a R9 380 (which could be better if I try a new BIOS, but I’m afraid to damage it, but could try later) running Claymore 9.7. This CPU has 1 Pci-e and 2 mini Pci but only 1 miniPciE is usable with a GPU attached in the main PCie slot
- A notebook i7 2630QM was unused last 3 years then I put it to work is making about 66/hs with 8 threads (same of i5, notebook sucks).
- 2 Computers i3 2120 running cpuminer-sse2 who brings together about 50/hs (They are fileservers and stay idle most of time anyway and for
  these 2 the energy is free).

My unused equipment:

- A i 650 with 2GB RAM (was 4GB before one of Ram finish) with 2 PCie slots free working but only missing it’s PSU
- A Empty thermaltake Element G - http://www.thermaltake.com/products-model.aspx?id=C_00001440  (My finished i7 720 was here 6 months ago after six years of fun, I love this case, really).

What are coming next week (Already bought):

- A Rx580 8gb Sapphire Radeon Nitro+ (https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814202293)
- A PSU Sharkoon WPC650 650W ATX 80 Plus Bronze to put into unused i5 650 or with other new pc with my element G Case.

I’d like suggestions to make a effective farm using pcs to mine Monero and maybe Etherium in the future. I have more $4000 to spent but I’d like to keep and use these 3 cases not a rig to stay simple and not to worry my family with using more space, that why I’m thinking only in GPUs inside these 3 cases and any device who has a processor and can mine (if my 3DS and old iPOD 3Gs could mine, they would be working now).
I was thinking to use this Rx580 with i5 650 and buy to another one or I could buy a Ryzen 7 1800X or a Ryzen Threadripper 1920X (but I don’t know if Worth to mine) with a Motherboard who can hold 3 GPUs then I could to get more 3 Rx580, a SSD, 16GB RAM (2x8GB DDR4) and a PSU good enough.

Is there any advice?

Is worth to use EthOs in these PCs during dedicated mining?

I don’t want make profit now, if the mined coins pay the energy bill and If I can keep the change its ok, with Monero and others cryptocoins I want just buy and hold for now.

About mining I was thinking to leave the pool and go solo mining making my own private pool or solo mining with every device in my house, but I don’t know if it is worth.

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 3):

With that budget I'd probably build a rig around the following components:

- AsRock H110 Pro BTC+ (~140€)
- 6xMSI GTX 1060 GAMING X6G (~360€ each = 2160€ total)

One GTX 1060 overclocked using the following settings will be able to sustain about 540 H/s resulting in 3.2 kH/s with very moderate power consumption:

- Core Clock +200 MHz
- Memory Clock +800 MHz
- Power Limit 65%

**Update:**

Out of curiosity I've ran [XMRig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/releases/download/v2.2.1/xmrig-2.2.1-gcc7-xenial-amd64.tar.gz) on the AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X hosting my beta pool and achieved approx. 1 KH/s using just the CPU. So in theory you could also build three CPU only rigs using that CPU at slightly higher cost but with reduced power consumption (Ryzen 1950X TDP is 180W) and the added benefit of sparing you the hassle of wiring and cooling all those GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

you should use some AMD sapphire radeon rx 64s because they have just shy of 2kh/s each and only use about 150 watts per card for mining. I do agree with the motherboard though because it has the ability to reinvest and hold up to 13 gpus!